# Use cron to fetch a view which contains jQuery content?

Tags: php, jquery, drupal-7, cron

Is there a way I can set a cron to run a view on my Drupal site? I have a jQuery script on it which I would like to run once an hour.

I tried;

```
php http://mysite/myview
```

but I guess I am waaay off the mark. I get;

```
Could not open input file:
```

Here's the js which I am using on my rss feed;

```
// $Id
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.tweetcast = {

attach: function (context, settings) {

$('div.tagspeak:not(.tags-processed)', context).addClass('tags-processed').each(function () {

var mynid, sinceid, updateinfo, sinceurl, author, tweethtml;
var currentsinceid = $('.currentsinceid').val();

var firstring = $(this).html();
var twostring = firstring.replace(/\s/g,'').replace(/^%20OR%20/gim,'').replace(/%20OR$/gim,'').replace(/%20OR%20%$/gim,'').replace(/%20OR%20$/gim,'').replace(/%$/gim,'').replace(/%20OR$/gim,'').toLowerCase();  
var threestring = twostring.replace(/%20or%20/gim,'%20OR%20');
$(this).text(threestring);
var fourstring = threestring.replace(/%20OR%20/gim,' ');
var fivestring = fourstring.replace(/%23/gim,'#');

$(this).closest('.views-row').append('<div class="views-field views-field-replies"></div>');    
tweethtml = $(this).closest('.views-row').find('div.views-field-replies').eq(0);

var twitter_api_url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json';
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });

$.getJSON( twitter_api_url + '?callback=?&rpp=1&q=' + threestring + '&since_id=' + currentsinceid, function(data) {
$.each(data.results, function(i, tweet) {console.log(tweet);

    if(tweet.text !== undefined) {

    var tweet_html = '<div class="tweetuser">' + tweet.from_user + '</div>';
    tweet_html  += ' <div class="sinceid">' + tweet.id + '</div>';
    tweethtml.append(tweet_html);

    }
});
});
    $.fn.delay = function(time, callback){
    jQuery.fx.step.delay = function(){};
    return this.animate({delay:1}, time, callback);
    }

    $(this).delay(2000, function(){
    title = $(this).closest('.views-row').find('div.views-field-title').eq(0).find('span.field-content').text();
    link = $(this).closest('.views-row').find('div.views-field-path').eq(0).find('span.field-content').text();
    author = $(this).closest('.views-row').find('div.tweetuser').eq(0).text();
    mynid = $(this).closest('.views-row').find('div.mynid').text();
    sinceid = $(this).closest('.views-row').find('div.sinceid').eq(0).text();
    updateinfo = {sinceid: sinceid, mynid: mynid, author: author, title: title, link: link, tags: fivestring};
    sinceurl = Drupal.settings.basePath + 'sinceid';

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: sinceurl,
    data: updateinfo,
    success: function(){}
    });
    });
});
}}
})
(jQuery);
```

And here is the php  my module;

```
<?php
// $id:
function sinceid_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['sinceid'] = array(
  'title' => 'sinceid',
  'page callback' => 'sinceid_count',
  'description' => 'sinceid',
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
return $items;
}
function sinceid_count() 
{
$sinceid=$_POST['sinceid'];
$mynid=$_POST['mynid'];
$author=$_POST['author'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$link=$_POST['link'];
$tags=$_POST['tags'];

db_update('node')
->expression('sinceid', $sinceid)
->condition('nid', $mynid)
->execute();

$sql = db_query("SELECT author FROM {authordupe} WHERE author = $author");
$result = db_query($sql);
$how_many_rows = $result->rowCount();
if($how_many_rows == 0) {

db_insert('authordupe')
->fields(array(
'author' => $author,
'title' => $title,
'link' => $link,
'tags' => $tags,
))
->execute();



}   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic code to run a view in Drupal is

```
$view = views_get_view('<your_view_machine_name>');
$view->set_display('<optional_display_name>');
$view->execute();
```

That said, you say have a jQuery script that runs within a view. Seriously? What is your script doing? I'd say that jQuery it's best used when you want a script to be run at client's side. Can't you write php code to accomplish whatever you need and put it in a cron hook?

Comment: Ummm... very embarrassed but... I'm not a php programmer. I know little bit of jquery. I know it's ugly...but I am limited in my abilities...I'll edit my original post and add the code. I've got views creating an rss feed which I am modifying with regex in jquery and posting to twitter.

Comment: The problem here is that you are trying to execute a jQuery script, which typically runs in browser. I still believe that you'd better use a cron hook within your module to load the appropriate nodes and build the rss to post to twitter. Or you could give a try [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) if you still think you prefer the jQuery solution (I never used myself, but looks promising...)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the right way! I will take your suggestion to either write a module and I will also look into using PhantomJS which looks promising.